# Building a 2x8 memory using flip-flops and logic gates

Tags: digital-logic, memory, computer-architecture, logisim

The image represents a 4x3 memory.Build a 2x8 memory.[image]

Comment: And? Did you build it? Did you try building it?

Comment: no i'm stuck,I dont know how.

Comment: Can't you identify the pattern on the schematic?  What "4" corresponds to? What "3" corresponds to? What you need to do to change these to "2" and "8"?

Comment: Sorry, we won't do your homework for you. You say you are "stuck" but it doesn't look like you even tried. Show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself, then come back if you have a **specific** question.

Comment: OP if you are able to ask a question, stack is able to respond to it although it's homework. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Bjoni 4 is row and 3 is column

Comment: Bem not homework without any effort in the exercise(s)

Comment: Im understand your point guys.Its just this subject is hard for me too understand.

Comment: Thanks for èverybody who took their time to read my problem.

Comment: Bjoni I like middle solution so here's what we are going to do. Try it hard for 2 hours by yourself and if you still can't figure it out post where you are stuck and we will help you.

Comment: alright i will give it a try

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not help you.

First, redraw the schematic so that it is less convoluted.

Remove the zig-zags from the input and output lines.

Find common "blocks" and spread them out to make the schematic less "dense".

Use color to clarify some of the signals.

You'll get something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I build your circuit with an online simulator. I think it is best to use a simulator to evaluate your approach.

https://electra.academy/simulator/?shared=47c57dd2eb0c93c0d9aeb38fabd82c5e772158a6

This is a good starting point to go into the right direction for your solution. The "address decoder" is in you case pretty simple. It is only a simple on/off switch. You have only two memory cell. In this case only two states are required. 0 and 1

The rest it pretty simple.